# netty and web socket support

Tags: websocket, netty

Does netty support web socket connections and handling?

I have implemented a basic TCP/IP server working with my clients and wanted to change this over to web sockets.

Is there built in support for this?

Answer (score 0):

The upcomming 3.3.0 release does contain support for websockets.

Checkout:
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2

This will be released as 3.3.0 shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Netty 3.3.0 supports the latest Websocket versions.

Please see http://netty.io/blog/2012/01/19/.

It is already available in the Maven repository.